# How-to RewiteRule for two scenario files?

Tags: .htaccess

i have such .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
# http://site.com/ru,ua,lt/anything/
RewriteRule ^(ru|ua|lt)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2
# http://site.com/print/ru,ua,lt/anything/
RewriteRule ^print/(ru|ua|lt)/([^/]+)/$ print.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2
```

First example(# http://site.com/ru,ua,lt/anything/) works, second not work. Please help solve situation.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Post details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http://site.com/ru,ua,lt/anything/
RewriteRule ^(ru|ua|lt)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

# http://site.com/print/ru,ua,lt/anything/
RewriteRule ^print/(ru|ua|lt)/([^/]+)/?$ print.php?lang=$1&article_id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Then try out your URIs and report back if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What does not work? Is it only external files (JS, CSS, Images) that do not work?

This could be the case, for your second URL has an additional sub directory. You should then use absolute URL paths to link to external files.

Comment: Does not show print.php with echo GET[lang] and GET[article_id] parameters!